# Customizing error report page for multi site

Tags: error, multistore

I have 3 stores with subdirectory method.
I customized error page and this shows properly on the main store A.
However, store B and C (which are on sub directories) do not show customized one and instead showing the default one.

In my local.xml under errors folder, I have

```
<config>
    <skin>mytheme</skin>
    <report>
        <action>email</action>
        <subject>Store Debug Information</subject>
        <email_address>my@email.com</email_address>
        <trash>leave</trash>
    </report>
</config>
```

and index.php under store B and C subdirectory have

```
if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../errors/503.php';
    exit;
}
```

What could be the reason??

I also see on the browser that store B, for example, is trying to load style.css from mystore.com/en/errors/default/css/styles.css 
which should be mystore.com/errors/mytheme/css/styles.css

Comment: What if you remove `dirname(__FILE__) . ` from your files ? Edit: remove the first slash as well.

Comment: still not working

Comment: I also see on the browser that store B, for example, is trying to load style.css from http://mystore.com/en/errors/default/css/styles.css